# How to whitelist Apple and Google to access deep link association files?

Tags: ios-universal-links, android-app-links

We have implemented Universal Links for iOS and Android App Links.

We have deployed the following files as per the documentation:

```
/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Everything works fine until my organization applied domain-level block on traffic out side my country.

We need to whitelist Apple and Google servers but I cannot find their IPs or domain used to access those files.

Comment: If in case you need IP mean just Ping using ```$ ping google.com ``` in cmd or terminal

Comment: You can change TDL according to country e.g if UK means use ```$ ping google.co.uk```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow all subdomains of Apple & Google to access your servers in the companies firewall,

According to apple, and google, if you are using their products and services in an enterprise environment (e.g. behind a firewall), you should whitelist the following addresses and subdomains:

for **Apple**: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

for **Google**: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en

and for google also check these lists:

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322
- https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/access-apis-external-ip#config